# Cannot create nor download any files to Google bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

I mounted the bucket on a directory with full permissions (+777) using `gcsfuse` but I cannot create/download/copy any files to that bucket. I get: `Permission denied`

This is the permissions configuration of such bucket:
[image]

Why despite being an owner of the project am I unable to edit anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it changing the access scopes of my virtual machine to full access. [image]